# vertical center table in a div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to place a table in the center vertically but I can't do it. I have seen that it can be achieved with vertical-aligning but it doesn't work for me. Place it at the beginning of the div. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="col-12 d-flex">
    <div class="col-6 text-center default_color" style="padding-top: 5rem;">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-12 " *ngIf="!incompleteDataForTables">
          <b style="color:var(--select-bg-color)">Variación entre semanas sites </b>
      <div class="col-12"  style="vertical-align: middle">
          <div class="table-responsive m-2 p-1 " style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 100%;vertical- 
           align: middle">
              <table id="data_week_comp_3500" style="vertical-align: middle">
             </table>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are already using bootstrap, try this

```
<div class="col-12 d-flex">
  <div class="col-6 text-center default_color" style="padding-top: 5rem;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12" *ngIf="!incompleteDataForTables">
        <b style="color: var(--select-bg-color);"
          >Variación entre semanas sites</b
        >
        <div
          class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
          style="height: 100vh; background-color: yellow;"
        >
          <div class="table-responsive m-2 p-1">
            <table id="data_week_comp_3500" class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Header 1</th>
                  <th>Header 2</th>
                  <th>Header 3</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Data 1</td>
                  <td>Data 2</td>
                  <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Data 4</td>
                  <td>Data 5</td>
                  <td>Data 6</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Added class
d-flex, align-items-center and mx-auto

Comment: thanks but don`t work

Comment: I have created a codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vertical-center-table-in-a-div-2dj46r